# How to ensure that gid in /etc/passwd also exist in /etc/group

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Background: The Unclassified RHEL 6 Security Technical Implementation Guide (STIG), a DoD guide, specifies in (STID-ID) RHEL-06-000294 that all user primary GIDs appearing in /etc/passwd must exist in /etc/group.

Instead of running the recommended 'pwck -rq' command and piping to a log then forcing the admin to manually remediate, it makes more sense to programmatically check if the users GID exists and, if not, simply set it to something which does exist such as "users" or "nobody"

I've been beating my head against this and can't quite get it.  I've failed at sed, awk, and some piping of grep into sed or awk.  The problem seems to be when I attempt to nest commands.  I learned the hard way that awk won't nest in one-liners (or possibly at all).

The pseudo-code for a more traditional loop looks something like:

```
# do while not EOF /etc/passwd
#   GIDREF = get 4th entry, sepparator ":" from line
#   USERNAMEFOUND = get first entry, separator ":" from line
#   grep ":$GIDREF:" /etc/group
#   if not found then
#      set GID for USERNAMEFOUND to "users"
#   fi
# end-do.
```

This seems like it should be quite simple but I'm apparently missing something.

Thanks for the help.

-Kirk

Comment: Delete all the background stuff about govt regulations etc. and just post some sample input (i.e. typical content of both files you want to operate on) and expected output from that input and a description of the mapping in terms of fields by row and column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List all GIDs from `/etc/passwd` that don't exist in `/etc/group`:

```
comm -23 <(awk -F: '{print $4}' /etc/passwd | sort -u) \
         <(awk -F: '{print $3}' /etc/group  | sort -u)
```

Fix them:

```
nogroup=$(awk -F: '($1=="nobody") {print $3}' /etc/group)
for gid in $(
 comm -23 <(awk -F: '{print $4}' /etc/passwd | sort -u) \
          <(awk -F: '{print $3}' /etc/group  | sort -u)); do
  awk -v gid="$gid" -F: '($4==gid) {print $1}' /etc/passwd | 
   xargs -n 1 usermod -g "$nogroup"
done
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks. I especially appreciate the check for nobody gif. Very clever.

Comment: Sorry.  When I posted, I wasn't in an environment that was sympathetic to that particular function. Now "accepted."  :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking along these lines:

```
if ! grep "^$(groups $USERNAME | cut -d\  -f 1):" /etc/group > /dev/null; then
  usermod -g users $USERNAME
fi
```

Where

```
groups $USERNAME | cut -d\  -f 1
```

gives the primary group of `$USERNAME` by splitting the output of `groups $USERNAME` at the first space (before the `:`) and

```
grep ^foo: /etc/group
```

checks if group foo exists.

EDIT: Fix in the code: quoting and splitting at space instead of colon to allow the appended colon in the grep pattern (otherwise, `grep ^foo` would have also said that group `foo` existed if there was a group `foobar`).

Comment: Thanks. Looks like this could be compressed onto one line if needed. Nice. :)